# how to consider regex expression as block to apply lookbehids and lookaheads?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, infinite-loop

I'm trying to turn a string of this type:

`http://example.com/mypage/272-16+276-63+350-02`

where `aaa-bb` are product codes and their numbers may vary from 2 to anything, but I doubt there will ever be more than 5 into:

`http://example.com/mypage/272-16+276-63+350-02/?skus=272-16+276-63+350-02`

using a redirect match. I'm fairly new to regular expressions and I don't seem to be able to get the negative lookahead and lookbehind to work the way I want.

To capture the string the first time is fairly easy, I used `([\-\+0-9]+)` but I don't want it to match on redirection (when I already have a ? in my link). Using `([\-\+0-9]+)(?!\?)(?<\?)` doesn't do the trick, it only excludes my last digit from the match. So, is there a way to make regex consider all my product codes as one block, so I can than check if there is a question mark before or after it?

Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: What is the language/technology that you are using that you use this regex for?

Comment: Really not sure what you're asking, can you clarify the question and provide succinct examples and what you want matched?

Comment: @nhahtdh: It's a WP website, this goes into .htaccess

Comment: @remus: basically I want to put redirect from first link to second using a redirect match without having an infinite redirect loop.

Comment: Does the RegEx actually need to *validate* that all product codes are the same format as well? ie. `272-16+2-63+350-02` would *not* match because the second product's first digits are not 3 in length.

Comment: Still doesn't help. See my first comment.

Comment: @tenub no, it doesn't. and the skus can be with or without dash. they are devided by + signs and the dash separates the parent id from variation id. `1234+5679+123-1234+3-14` is another example of matched string.

Comment: I think you need a `RewriteCond` to check whether Query string is there or not before applying the rule.

Comment: He wants to manipulate `http://example.com/mypage/272-16+276-63+350-02 ` to read as `http://example.com/mypage/272-16+276-63+350-02/?skus=272-16+276-63+350-02`, but if the string being checked is already `http://example.com/mypage/272-16+276-63+350-02/?skus=272-16+276-63+350-02` it should not manipulate it further when the RegEx checks it. Basically need to do a `preg_replace` on the string with a condition that no `/?` exists at the end of the match, or simply check for query string.

Comment: @remus: i want to capture all +,-,and digits into one group and than I want to look if there is any question mark before or after that group. If there is not question mark, I match, if there is, I don't match. I hope this clarifies what I want to do.

Comment: This `(?<\?)` is not a valid assertion `([\-\+0-9]+)(?!\?)(? <-- Quantifies nothing <\?)`

Comment: @nhahtdh following your suggestion, I looked up some RewriteCond resources to learn how to do that. I came up with
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !skus=
RedirectMatch 301 /mypage/([\-\+0-9]+) /mypage/$1?skus=$1`
Isn't this supposed to work? It still gives me a redirection loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix mod_rewrite (RewriteCond) and mod_alias (RedirectMatch) together. You need to stick with one or the other and you can't match the query string with a RedirectMatch, so you're using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !skus=
RewriteRule ^mypage/([\-\+0-9]+)$ /mypage/$1?skus=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `(?<=http://example.com/mypage/)[0-9+-]+$` Will match only the first case.